# Creating a new MailAddress produces "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address", although it is in the correct format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create a new MailAddress, the email is coming from Request Parameters, that is: `Request.Params("fromEmail")`. It is actually being sent from an android device through an http request.
 When I try to create a new MailAddress from this email, I get the error "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address". When trying to create it directly, that it `ma=new MailAddress("a@b.com")` using the same coming string, it works, but creating it using `ma=new MailAddress(Convert.ToString(Request.Params("fromEmail"))` produces the error. I suspect there are some special caharacters being sent and making the email format unrecognizable, how can this be fixed

Thanks

Comment: Simply check the output of `Convert.ToString(Request.Params("fromEmail")`. You will see, it is not "a@b.com".

Comment: Actually it is the output of Convert.ToString(Request.Params("fromEmail") that I am using ( from QuickWatch Window) and it working fine! it is just when I am using Convert.ToString(Request.Params("fromEmail") the problem appears, and what is surprising me the most is that the out is "a@b.com",

Comment: Try this: `var param = Convert.ToString(Request.Params("fromEmail")); if(param != "a@b.com") throw new InvalidOperationException(); else ma = new MailAddress(param);` - does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you have an encoding problem, or a non-printing character in the parameter.

Comment: yes the problem was actually that a "\n" character was being sent from the Android device, the "\n" failed to appear in the quick watch window